# Impact of migrating to Signature Version 4 in AWS SES where we use AWS SES SMTP credentials in sending email in PHP application?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, smtp, amazon-ses

We have recently got an email from Amazon.

```
Hello,

Amazon Web Services currently supports Amazon SES API requests that are signed using Signature 
Version 3 and Signature Version 4 processes. Signature Version 4 further enhances the security around 
authentication and authorization of Amazon SES customers by using a signing key instead of your 
secret access key. To improve the security for our customers, beginning October 1, 2020, Amazon 
Signature Version 3 will be turned off (deprecated) in Amazon SES in favor of Signature Version 4.

Amazon SES customers who are still using Signature Version 3 must migrate to Signature Version 4 by 
September 30, 2020. After that, Amazon SES will only accept requests that are signed using Signature 
Version 4. For more information, see Signature Version 4 signing process [1].

What Happens if I Don't Make Updates?

Requests signed with Signature Version 3 that are made after September 30, 2020 will fail to 
authenticate with Amazon SES. Requesters will see errors stating that the request must be signed with 
Signature Version 4.

References:
[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

Sincerely,
Amazon Web Services

Amazon Web Services, Inc. is a subsidiary of Amazon.com, Inc. Amazon.com is a registered trademark of 
Amazon.com, Inc. This message was produced and distributed by Amazon Web Services Inc., 410 Terry 
Ave. North, Seattle, WA 98109-5210
```

We have several PHP Codeigniter applications where we use Amazon SES SMTP credentials to send email. we don't use AWS Access Key & Secret Key to send email. So I assume this migration to Signature Version 4 wont affect on our application. Can anyone assure me that if my assumption is correct ?

Answer (score 3):

If you’re using SMTP  to send emails using SES, sigv4 shouldn’t affect you, it’s only for sendemail or sendrawemail api calls.

Comment: how to upgrade @James Dean

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that. According to Amazon's docs here regarding SMTP credentials, if you have SES SMTP credentials created before January 2019, they recommend changing them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html

Comment: @JamesWhite I agree. I was initially confused since the first article I found made all sorts of reference to web service, HTTP and Headers, etc. But we aren't using any of that - just SMTP. Then I found this article - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html. I followed the instructions and generated the new v4 password. Using the original account id and the newly signed password I am able to send via SMTP. So I believe that the upgrade to v4 is necessary even if you are using the SMTP interface.

Comment: I'm not sure what the sig4 password adds over the original password. They are both static passwords. The sig4 password uses a hardcoded date of '11111111'.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SES SMTP credentials to send emails using SMTP you may still be affected. SES SMTP credentials are signed, and previous to February 2019 AWS used SignatureV2 when generating credentials via the SES console. A [forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=334087&tstart=0) from an AWS employee confirms this:

> If you are referring to the communication sent to a few customers to migrate from V2 credentials to V4 credentials for Smtp, yes, even if you don't use the SDK, you have to do that.

Comment: I did see that Chris.. So I created a new IAM user for SES only on Monday. Using AWS's published Powershell code I sent several test emails through those new creds. The biggest part of my issue is that I cannot tell if the new Creds are version 4 or not. I mean AWS says to just recreate them but I can't find a way to prove that.

Comment: @Skeer Instead of creating the IAM user for sending raw SMTP emails on the IAM console you should instead create it on the SES console under SMTP Settings > Create My SMTP Credentials. When creating it on the SES console the credentials will be pre-signed using the V4 signature.